# (The) companies engaged in this field - is article needed?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

> In the year 2014, Uzbekistan's chemical production grew by 9% relative to 2013. In the period under report, **the** companies engaged in the field increased their outputs of the following products: potassium chloride (+14%), sodium nitrate (+18%) ...

Is the definite article necessary? From the context, what is meant is *all* of Uzbekistan's chemical companies taken together, so it logically should be **the**, because leaving no article would make it seem as if some companies' outputs are not included in the aggregate figures.

On the other hand, it reads a bit like "the companies *that we've mentioned previously*" due to the use of **the**.. or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you have a link? Also, what intrigues me is *of* in *in the year of 2014*? We say *in the spring of 2014* because spring is part of 2014, but is year part of 2015? Unless its short for *in the year of (our Lord) 2014*.

Comment: @δοῦλος - I composed it myself as an example. Thanks for the tip on the preposition **of**! Makes me blush to think that I used this construction. (0:

Comment: Not a problem. I could easily see people using *In the year of 2014*. Like *in the year-time-period consisting of 2014*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > In the year 2014, Uzbekistan's chemical production grew by 9% relative to 2013. In the period under report, **the** companies engaged in the field increased their outputs of the following products: potassium chloride (+14%), sodium nitrate (+18%) ...

1 Is the definite article necessary?

No

By including it, you are making a definite reference to *companies engaged in the field*. By making a *definite reference* you are referring to all the companies unless you otherwise state that you are not.

*Not including Company Firth,* the companies engaged in the field...

2 Would [leaving no article] make it seem as if some companies' outputs are not included in the aggregate figures?

First, *technically speaking* you are not "leaving no article" or even "using no article." You are using the zero-article rather than the definite article. The zero-article before a plural count noun is an *indefinite* reference.

An *indefinite reference* to a plural count noun with the zero-article is indefinite as to the number of companies. However, this indefinite  number **can** include all the companies.

Whereas, using *some companies* is also an indefinite reference to *companies engaged in the field*, and this also means an indefinite number (greater than 1) of companies, *some* **cannot** mean *all* the companies.

*Ex:*

> *Some* of his friends in Vladivostok are going to visit him at his home in Petersburg.

The use of *some* precludes or rules out the possibility, at least grammatically at the time of utterance, that *all* his friends in Vladivostok are traveling to Petersburg.

*Yet:*

> *Friends* of his in Vladivostok are going to visit him...

leaves open the possibility that this indefinite reference includes **all** his friends.

As far as

> On the other hand, it reads a bit like "the companies *that we've mentioned previously*" due to the use of **the**.. or maybe I'm wrong.

I wish **teachers** had never ever come up with this dual notion of (1) *a thing previously mentioned* takes *the* and (2) *a thing mentioned for the first time* takes *a*/*an*. Neither statement is true.

I can surmize that the reason it reads a bit like *companies we've mentioned previously* is because that is one context in which a writer can make a definite reference. But there are plenty of other such contexts, such as yours.

In your discourse, you have used *the* to make a definite reference because you assume that your readers can uniquely identify *which* companies you are referring to. Readers can so do from these sources: the complete noun phrase (*companies engaged in the field*), the context (talking about chemical production in Uzbekistan's chemical production), and general knowledge about the world (chemical production involves companies).

I have read that 75% of uses of the definite article are *first mentions*. This is because the overwhelming number of first mentions are identifiable from context, shared knowledge, general knowledge, and/or common sense. Just read any magazine or news article in English.

In both [fiction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44442/the-use-of-the-definite-article), and non-fiction, there is another use of *the* in first mention, which is to indicate a *topic*.

> I was walking home when I heard the bad news.

What do you think the *topic* will be in subsequent sentences? :)

On the other hand, one can consider that this use of *the* is simply a cataphoric definite reference to a referent whose unique identity will be made at a later time in the discourse (in other words, from context).

Answer (score 0):

> *that we've mentioned previously*

This is one of those rules that aren't rules. It does not apply to every situation, and not every use of *the* can be explained by it. In this case, it is *totally irrelevant*.

Your first interpretation is correct.

> The companies engaged in this field have increased their output.

**All** of them have increased their output.

> Companies engaged in this field have increased their output.

**Some** of them have increased their output.

Whether they were mentioned before or not is really not often important. You can very well specify the specific instance(s) you mean *after* you mention them:

> *The* reasons for doing this are complex.
>   *The* apples I ate tasted good.
>   It is *the* dawning of *the* age of Aquarius.
>   *The* only bad question is *the* one unasked.

Comment: I can't really agree with this. It's *possible* someone might mean ***some*** when they omit the article, but it's equally possible that their audience might assume ***all*** anyway. The only "true" aspect of such usages is that when the article *is* included, this very strongly implies ***all***. But the converse (no article implies ***some***) doesn't necessarily hold.

Comment: Agree with @FumbleFingers The use of the zero article is not equivalent with saying *some*.